# run continuous ping at startup

Tags: startup, ping, nohup

I'd like to have a script running in the background, which pings a remote host every 10 seconds or so. The script looks something like this:

`nohup ping -i 10 www.google.com &`

I'm able to initiate the script with an @reboot cron job, following [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/816/151617). However, the ping doesn't happen in the background and I don't see the script running when I poke around with `ps`.

Any suggestions much appreciated.    Thanks.

Comment: if you put it like that in cron I got a question where is ping located? (answer: always use absolute paths in cron unless you can tell it to use a PATH ;) )

Comment: Try the commands with absolute paths, as described by `type`. The command should be `/usr/bin/nohup /bin/ping -i 10 www.google.com &` .BUT! is name resolution (`dnsmasq`) up and running when `@reboot` runs? Try `@reboot host www.google.com`. I have a different suggestion, adapt this: https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic.git - Watch for (WiFi) network going down, then do a user-specified thing to fix it.

Comment: Why on earth do you need/want to ping google every 10 secs?

Comment: long-ish answer, I run a high school computer lab where computers are on wifi. I am having trouble at times ssh'ing to various boxes and I'm trying to determine if the radio is timing out. Hoping that a ping keep alive will keep the wifi interface alive. I have disabled the sleep / power save, but still having trouble. it may be network traffic ... when I started this project it seemed like it would be an easy route to get a keep alive like this going in the background. And hey, I learned a bit more about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to switch from using a cron job, to adding a script to `/etc/network/if-up.d/` as per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389877/script-in-etc-network-if-up-d-is-not-run-on-connection). Did some troubleshooting with `ifup --all -v` to get the details correct.